# Perforce server: running on public IP instead of 127.0.0.1

Tags: perforce

During the installation (on Windows Server 2012 ), the setup asks for the port and then the server runs on localhost (127.0.0.1).  When I try to connect to the server using the public IP of the computer, it wouldn't connect.   I tried using P4PORT setting to change localhost to Public IP. But then the Perforce service fails to launch (error 1067).  Not sure why would they bind the port by default to localhost.  Perforce works fine if a client on the same server tries to connect using localhost:1666, but obviously it is useless as clients on other computers cannot connect.  Any pointers?

[more details]
This server is a Azure VM.  It has an internal IP address and a Public IP address. On the same server, when I lauch P4Admin and enter `localhost:1666`, it works.  It also works when I enter `<computername>:1666`.  It also works when I use `<Internal IP>:1666`.  It DOES NOT work when I enter `<Public IP>:1666`.  The machine is fully accessible via the Internet using the public IP.

Comment: can you make it listen on 0.0.0.0 ?

Comment: Are you trying to connect to the public IP from a different host ?  If so, you probably have a firewall blocking the p4 port.

Comment: also when perforce server is running,  what does `netstat -an` show.  where do you see port 1666 listening ?

Comment: I opened port 1666 in firewall, but that doesn't appear to be an issue.  When I try to connect using the IP addess (with port 1666) from a client on the same server, it doesn't connect.  Only way a client connects is when I put localhost:1666

Comment: netstat -an      
 Proto  Local Address          Foreign Address        State
 TCP    0.0.0.0:135            0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
 TCP    0.0.0.0:445            0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
 TCP    0.0.0.0:1666           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
 TCP    0.0.0.0:3389           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
 TCP    0.0.0.0:5986           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
 TCP    0.0.0.0:47001          0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING

Comment: netstat -an shows that listing to 0.0.0.0:1666

Comment: I have added more info in the original message.  I guess what is missing is a some sort of port forwarding from external ip to internal ip?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Resolved.  In the Azure Portal, created a new endpoint with public port 1666 and private port 1666.  I guess it provides a mapping between external and internal IP addresses and ports.  Thanks everybody.